# When to consider friction as an impulsive force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, friction, collision

Suppose a ball obliquely strikes a rough horizontal surface then it experiences a frictional impulse and conservation of linear momentum cannot be done on the horizontal direction.

Now consider another setup in which one block is resting on a rough horizontal surface and another block moving towards the 1st block collides with it. 
Then is the momentum of the system conserved? I think that it should not be conserved because the value of friction acting on the system (combination of the 2 blocks) changes from zero to a non zero value. But in books I have seen that they apply conservation of linear momentum. Why do we consider frictional impulse in 1st setup and neglect frictional impulse in the second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We consider friction to an impulsive force, in cases when normal force is impulsive. Here's how:
We know that $f=\mu N$(only during slipping motion, for no slipping frictional force is equal to applied force RESISTING friction). Since friction is proportional to normal reaction, it will be impulsive only when normal force is impulsive.
Thus, if in a situation there is a sudden change in normal force, friction will be impulsive( part of reason why a water ballon or mud ball burst or distort when thrown to ground, because of impulsive friction due to impulsivee normal force.) 
 Therefore, in your question, since normal is impulsive in case 1 , momentum cant be conserved, but it can be done in case 2 because no extra force, tending to make normal force impulsive acts on system.

Comment: If we consider the block at rest:  Just before collision friction is not proportional to normal force as it has no tendency to move. But during collision it experiences friction, which is static I suppose, which is again does not depend on normal force. So why does the normal come into play when deciding whether the friction will be impulsive or not?

Comment: becuase the formula for friction(during slipping) is dependent upon normal force, and for no slliping there will be no force acting(in this case).

Comment: For no slipping static friction acts which is a force not dependent on normal. There is a frictional force acting. Isn't it?

Comment: It may only happen, if  force is applied. If no  force, then no friction.By that, I mean forces that tend to produce motion

Comment: Thats why I specifically mentioned "during slipping".

Comment: So in 2nd case force is acting on the block at rest due to collision, so it has a tendency to move so why are we neglecting frictional impulse on the basis of no change in normal force?

Comment: "frictional impulse"?. there will be be none since, because its magnitude will be finite(due to finite normal force), therefore conservation of momentum(only at collision), will be valid, because friction will NOT BE IMPULSIVE.

Comment: So if we can ignore the frictional impulse in the second case due to finiteness then why can't we ignore it too in the first case?

Comment: AS I said earlier, beacuse Normal force is not finite, and there will be NO "frictional impulse".

Comment: You mean that normal force is not finite in 1st case but it is finite in 2nd case. Right?

Comment: Exactly. Now you've got it correctly.

Comment: One last thing : how do we judge whether the normal force will be finite or not in a setup? And how do we judge whether a force will provide impulse to the system or not?

Comment: Calculate or observe the setup. If the collsion involves collison along perpendicular to surface, then normal will be impulsive because if the speed of the ball is very large normal will be large. Moreover, mentally observe the change in momemtum in case 1 and case 2 (in your question) along y direction

Comment: I did not get why the normal force is finite in 2nd and not finite in 1st one

Comment: In case 1, Impulse due to normal is $m(V_{1}+V_{2})$ and is case 2 chane in momemtum along  y direction is 0. Now in case 1 change will be only due to normal because since time of contact is small, thus change due to weight will be zero( or equivalently since it is a finite force).

Comment: That helped a lot.

Comment: Its alright. But hey, you've understood it, more importantly.